# Can I enable more key combinations for keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I'm wondering if there's any way to enable more key combinations to be used for various actions than those we can use through the standing keyboard shortcuts preference page. For instance using <kbd>left shift</kbd>+<kbd>right shift</kbd> as a keyboard shortcut to change the input language, or using <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> for grabbing a screenshot, etc.

Perhaps there's some hack I can use, or an external tool, or just some hidden preference?

Comment: FYI, there is an existing shortcut, cmd-shift-3, to take a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

[QuickKeys](http://startly.com/products/quickeys/mac/4/) allows you to record actions or define macros and assign them to keyboard shortcuts. I don't know if the Macintosh draws a distinction between <kbd>Right Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> though.

Comment: macOS allows for right vs left shift but only in some places such as the Mission Control preference screen.